# How do I add a background to a transparent png in gimp?

Tags: gimp, alpha-channel, image-transparency

I have a png file with a transparent background.  I would like to add a non-transparent background from a jpg.  I have tried:

1. Open the transparent png file.  I see the picture with the checkerboard background.
2. Open As Layers the non-transparent jpg file.  It covers the original picture.
3. Choose Stack -> Reverse Layer order.  What I see now looks like step 1.

I hoped that I would be able to see the non-transparent jpg picture through the png transparency, but I don't.  What should I do?  I am using Gimp 2.8.10 on OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: Add a new layer to the png, copy the non-transparent jpeg to the new layer in the png, lower the z-order of that layer (with the non-transparent jpeg).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, thanks, but I'm still seeing the same result, perhaps because I'm misunderstanding your instructions.  When I try copying the non-transparent jpeg into the new layer, a third layer always gets created, whether I use copy or copy-into.

Comment: That's fine. Just lower that layer in the layers tool.

Comment: It's working now.  I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy the new background layer image (click the select tool and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>) and then paste into a new layer in your target image (CTRL-<kbd>v</kbd>) which will create a new layer. Finally, lower that layer using the down-arrow in the "Layer" tool.